# Como declarar um tipo extendido em Typescript

Tags: typescript

Olá, tenho a seguinte situação:

```js
// essa classe contém apenas 2 propriedades
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

// em determinada situação, eu preciso declarar
// a interface junto com mais uma propriedade, assim
let Bar: ({ c: boolean } implements Foo); // não funciona
let Bar: { c: boolean } implements Foo;   // não funciona
let Bar: { c: boolean } implements Foo;   // não funciona
let Bar: { c: boolean } && Foo;           // não funciona
let Bar: [{ c: boolean } implements Foo]; // não funciona
let Bar: [{ c: boolean } && Foo];         // não funciona
```

a única forma que eu entendo que seja possível eu fazer isso seria declarar novamente a interface `Bar` assim

```js
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}
interface Bar extends Foo {
    c: boolean;
}
let Bar:Bar;
```

Existe alguma forma de estender as propriedades de um tipo na declaração (sem a necessidade de criação de uma interface externa? não creio que seja totalmente funcional eu fazer a declaração de uma nova interface que faça isso somente para atender essa situação.

Comment: Não funciona porque esta sintaxe não faz o menor sentido e não faz o que deseja, isso é uma invenção, não é que não permite estender o tipo.

Comment: @Maniero, sim a declaração dele não existe, mas tem uma sintaxe correta para isso, [como apresentei na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/355546/2998), apesar de eu nunca ter utilizado, prefiro declarar uma interface estendida.

Comment: @FernandoLeal a sua está correta, só não sei se resolve o que ele quer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia fazer algo como isso (que unirá as definições das duas declarações, que parece ser sua intenção):

```
let Bar: { c: boolean } & Foo;
```

Depois você pode acessar as propriedades normalmente:

```
let bar: { c: boolean } & Foo = {} as any;
bar.c = true;
bar.a = "hello";
bar.b = 2;
```

[Exemplo no StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jqoppz)

---

Uma outra maneira interessante e pratica é declarar um novo type:

```
type Bar = { c: boolean } & Foo;
```

E poderia utiliza-lo da seguinte forma, por exemplo:

```
let bar2: Bar = {} as any;
bar2.c = false;
bar2.a = "world";
bar2.b = 1;
```

Com a definição do tipo, se torna mais fácil referenciar esse mesmo tipo em outra partes do código, e até mesmo facilitaria uma refatoração e manutenção.

---

Não sei qual o termo correto para esse tipo de declaração (se algum souber ou tiver alguma referencia, por favor comente ou edite), mas segui a mesma ideia de múltiplos tipos para uma variável (Exemplo: `let x: string | number`), sendo que essa abordagem a variável deve conter um valor do tipo `string` ou `number`.

Não acho essa abordagem muito útil, pois me parece mais interessante criar uma nova interface estendendo de `Foo`, como você apresentou na pergunta. Pois assim você já terá esse novo tipo definido para ser declarado em todos os lugares onde ele for necessário. Mesmo assim a declaração simplificada pode ser utilizada para situação especificas.

Comment: É exatamente o que eu precisava